# Saving canvas as a PNG or JPG

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I want to save canvas as PNG, without opening it in a new window as base64-encoded image.

I used this code:

```
jQuery("#btnPreview").click(function(){
        if (!fabric.Canvas.supports('toDataURL')) {
            alert('Sorry, your browser is not supported.');
        }
        else {
            canvas.deactivateAll();
            canvas.forEachObject(function(o){
                if(o.get("title") == "||Watermark||"){
                    canvas.bringToFront(o);
                }
            });
            window.open(canvas.toDataURL('png'), "");
            canvas.forEachObject(function(o){
                if(o.get("title") == "||Watermark||"){
                    canvas.sendToBack(o);
                }
            });
            canvas.renderAll();
        }

    });
```

I want to make the button save the image as a PNG or JPG.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of this question.

Comment: i donot think that what i'm searching for :(

Comment: I want to save canvas as 'png' Without opening it in new window as base64 encoding image.

I want make the button save the image as a 'png' or 'jpg'
 i'm clear in that

Comment: Anyway To make it downloaded by PHP

Comment: @UXX1 - your question has only been up for roughly 30 minutes! Give it  some more time. You can edit your question to include the PHP question as well so more can see it.

Comment: In Firefox you can right click the canvas and choose "Save image as..." like you would with a normal image.

Answer (score 13):

I use this on my jquery:

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); 

$('.save').attr({
    'download': 'YourProduct.png',  /// set filename
    'href'    : image              /// set data-uri
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`canvas.toDataURL('png')` provides a string a la `data:image/png;base64,XYZ`. You could stuff that into an `<a href="%dataURI%" download>download</a>` (possibly trigger a click event on the element). See [Downloading resources in HTML5: a[download]](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download)

Currently supported only by Google Chrome, though.

Answer (score 1):

In script.js file

```
  $(document).on('click','#btnPreview',function(){
     var img =$scope.canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",   
                url: 'ajax.php', 
                data: {'img':img},
                success: function(data) { 
                    $("#loader_message").html("Image saved successfully"); 
                }
            });
  });
```

In ajax.php

```
    $encodedData=explode(',', $_POST["img"]);
    $data = base64_decode($encodedData[1]);
    $urlUploadImages = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$projName.'/images/canvas/';
    $nameImage = "test.png";
    $img = imagecreatefromstring($data);
     if($img) {
        imagepng($img, $urlUploadImages.$nameImage, 0);
        imagedestroy($img); 
        echo "OK";
    }
    else {
        echo 'ERROR';
    }
```

Comment: Its saving on the server folder named 'canvas'

Comment: I mean the question was "how to save locally". I know what your code is supposed to do, that's why I'm pointing out it doesn't actually answers the question.